# SSRS 2008 - How to hide the plus icon in a group visibility toggle cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that shows or hides columns in a group based on a header cell. SSRS makes this pretty easy and is kind enough to place a little plus/minus icon in the toggling cell.

I want to HIDE this plus/minus icon when there is only one column of data in the subgroup, because it shows that one column by default so expanding the group doesn't do anything.

This really only applies to one specific group, because all the others always have more than one column of data, so a way to hide only the icon for a specific group would be fine. JavaScript won't work (I don't think) because the client ID of the plus/minus image is generated by the report and changes with each generation.

see this image for more clarity: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKomS.png

Answer (score 8):

What I usually do is create a narrow column just to the left of the column that the header cell is in and set the cell to the left of the header cell to be the ToggleItem. You can then set the Hidden property of that cell with an expression based on the count.

Answer (score 2):

I have had similar problem with "plus" sign in my report. And I solved it this way:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This won't be possible.  To achieve what you need, the "Display can be toggled by this report item" setting would need to be expression-based. But unfortunately that's not the case.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected this was the case.