# SSRS toggle only certain rows

Tags: reporting-services, toggle, visibility

Say I have got a table with two columns:
The first one belongs to the parent row, the second one the child row. With generic data the output might look something like this:

```
 column1  column 2

 1          
            a
            b

 2
            c
            d
            e

 3
            f
            g
```

I have set the visibility of the child group (here in column 2) to be toggled by the values in the parent group (which here are in column 1).
E.g., the values "c, d, and e" can be toggled by clicking a + sign next to "2".

Now comes my problem:
I would like to make certain parts of the table disappear. For example, I would like the parent group "3" including the child member "f, g" not to be shown in my table. For this, I would have to set the visibility of the parent as well as the child group to something like

```
 =Fields!Parentgroup.Value=3.
```

However, when doing so, the first row of group "3" stays visible because of the toggle option.

A possible workaround would be to limit the toggle option only to rows containing certain data - but my researches showed this is not possible.

Any ideas for other workarounds? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you expand on the comment "I would like to make certain parts of the table disappear"? Do you want to hide these parts when the report runs or do you want to give the user a way to hide the entire group interactively?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I want to make the users choose interactively  which rows to keep. Filtering on the dataset in combination with multi-valued parameters are the way to go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to completely remove section 3 from the report, then you could put a filter on the dataset or on the table/matrix.  If you want it to toggle, then you have to keep the toggle element visible.

Comment: Thanks a million! A filter in combination with a multi-valued parameter was just was I needed!

Answer (score 0):

the below links provides an option to remove [+] sign against those rows where details section doesn't contain any data.

[SSRS 2008 - How to hide the plus icon in a group visibility toggle cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822276/ssrs-2008-how-to-hide-the-plus-icon-in-a-group-visibility-toggle-cell)

[how do i hide the toggle image if there is no row when using drilldown](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9c0f0180-b55f-43c6-8635-92ecb43b0f2b/forum-faq-how-do-i-hide-the-toggle-image-if-there-is-no-row-when-using-drilldown?forum=sqlreportingservices)